# Best way to group array with same value

Tags: php, arrays

I need your help to solve this :)

i've this array

```
    Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [order_id] => 121 [item_id] => 4344 [item_name] => Product [item_price] => 123 [item_type] => product [paypal_address] => email@test.com [qty] => 4 [currency] => EUR ) 
    [1] => Array ( [order_id] => 121 [item_id] => 3444 [item_name] => Product1 [item_price] => 444 [item_type] => product [paypal_address] => email@test.com [qty] => 2 [currency] => EUR ) 
    [2] => Array ( [order_id] => 121 [item_id] => 1233 [item_name] => Product2 [item_price] => 120 [item_type] => product [paypal_address] => email2@test.com [qty] => 18 [currency] => EUR ) 
)
```

I would like to loop on it and group them by values into a new array.

**For example:**

Pick all items in array that have the same paypal_address sum price, sum qty and move it into new array.

This is what i want to achieve, any tip / suggestion ?

**EDIT:** 
At the end i want an array like this or similar:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [order_id] => 121 [items_id] => array(4344, 3444) [items_name] => 'Product , Product1' [amt] => 567 [item_type] => product [paypal_address] => email@test.com [qty] => 8 [currency] => EUR )
    [1] => Array ( [order_id] => 121 [items_id] => 1233 [items_name] => Product2 [amt] => 120 [item_type] => product [paypal_address] => email2@test.com [qty] => 18 [currency] => EUR ) 
)
```

**EDIT2:**
what i did so far. but it doesn't work well and is not good to read.

```
        $groupedParams = array();
        foreach($params as $key=>$param){
            if(!array_key_exists($param['paypal_address'], $groupedParams) && $param['item_type'] == 'product'){
                $groupedParams[$param['paypal_address']] = array(
                    'order_id' => $param['order_id'],
                    'item_id' => $param['item_id'],
                    'item_name' => $param['item_name'],
                    'qty' => $param['qty'],
                    'amt' => $param['item_price'],
                    'item_type' => $param['item_type']
                );
            }else if(array_key_exists($param['paypal_address'], $groupedParams) && $param['item_type'] == 'product'){
                $newItemId = $groupedParams[$param['paypal_address']]['item_id'].','.$param['item_id'];
                $newAmt = (int)$groupedParams[$param['paypal_address']]['amt']+(int)$param['item_price'];
                $newQty = (int)$groupedParams[$param['paypal_address']]['qty']+(int)$param['qty'];
                $newItemName = (string)$groupedParams[$param['paypal_address']]['item_name'].' - '.(int)$param['item_name'];

                $groupedParams[$param['paypal_address']] = array(
                    'order_id' => $param['order_id'],
                    'item_id' => $newItemId,
                    'item_name' => $newItemName,
                    'qty' => $newQty,
                    'amt' => $newAmt,
                    'item_type' => $param['item_type']
                );
            }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Show example of your desired output array

Comment: Your original arrays have no `amt` key while desired one has

Comment: What problem you're trying to solve? You got this array from JOIN query and now trying to render in HTML nicely?

Comment: Looking at it, would it not be more beneficial to have something similar to:

Array (
 ['email@test.com'] => Array ( 
  Array ( [order_id] => 121 [item_id] => 4344 [item_name] => Product [item_price] => 123 [item_type] => product [qty] => 4 [currency] => EUR ), 
  Array ( [order_id] => 121 [item_id] => 3444 [item_name] => Product1 [item_price] => 444 [item_type] => product [qty] => 2 [currency] => EUR )  
 ),
 ['email2@test.com'] => Array ( 
  Array ( [order_id] => 121 [item_id] => 1233 [item_name] => Product2 [item_price] => 120 [item_type] => product [qty] => 18 [currency] => EUR ) 
 )
);

Comment: output structure doesn't make sense. At least figure out what you need specifically. Then make an attempt to solve yourself

Comment: ye is a good and more usable alternative. But i'm not figuring out how to group them without being dirty

Comment: Well then can I get your original code so I can whip something up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to reorganise it to a cleaner format from what I understand, simply put:

```
$array = array();
foreach($params as $ar) {
    $array[$ar['paypal_address']][] = $ar;
}
```

Example: http://jdl-enterprises.co.uk/sof/25767688.php

Answer (score 0):

1. Get Array and its values
2. make unique key on paypal_address
3. Use unique key to create temp array
4. Store all values with respective unique key in temp array

   ```
       $arr =     Array (
           '0' => Array ( 'order_id' => 121 ,'item_id' => 4344 ,'item_name' => 'Product' ,'item_price' => 123 ,'item_type' => 'product' ,'paypal_address' => 'email@test.com' ,'qty' => 4 ,'currency' => 'EUR' ) ,
           '1' => Array ( 'order_id' => 121 ,'item_id' => 3444 ,'item_name' => 'Product1' ,'item_price' => 444 ,'item_type' => 'product' ,'paypal_address' => 'email@test.com' ,'qty' => 2 ,'currency' => 'EUR' ) ,
           '2' => Array ( 'order_id' => 121 ,'item_id' => 1233 ,'item_name' => 'Product2' ,'item_price' => 120 ,'item_type' => 'product' ,'paypal_address' => 'email2@test.com' ,'qty' => 18 ,'currency' => 'EUR' )
       );
       $tmpArr = Array();
       $cnt = sizeof($arr);
       for($i=0;$i<$cnt;$i++){
               $paypal_address = $arr[$i]['paypal_address'];
               if(!is_array($tmpArr[$paypal_address])){
                       $tmpArr[$paypal_address] = Array();
               }
               $tmpArr[$paypal_address]['paypal_address'] = $arr[$i]['paypal_address'];
               $tmpArr[$paypal_address]['order_id'] = $arr[$i]['order_id'];
               $tmpArr[$paypal_address]['item_name'][] = $arr[$i]['item_name'];
               $tmpArr[$paypal_address]['item_type'][] = $arr[$i]['item_type'];
               $tmpArr[$paypal_address]['currency'][] = $arr[$i]['currency'];


               $tmpArr[$paypal_address]['qty'] = isset($tmpArr[$paypal_address]['qty']) ? $tmpArr[$paypal_address]['qty'] + $arr[$i]['qty'] : $arr[$i]['qty'];
               $tmpArr[$paypal_address]['item_id'] = $arr[$i]['item_id'];
               $tmpArr[$paypal_address]['item_id'][] = $item_id;
               $tmpArr[$paypal_address]['item_price'] = isset($tmpArr[$paypal_address]['item_price']) ? $tmpArr[$paypal_address]['item_price'] + $arr[$i]['item_price'] : $arr[$i]['item_price'];

       }
       print_r($tmpArr);
   ```

Output of the array is as below:

```
    Array([email@test.com] => Array ([paypal_address] => email@test.com[order_id] => 121[item_name] => Array  ( [0] => Product [1] => Product1  )[item_type] => Array  ( [0] => product [1] => product  )[currency] => Array  ( [0] => EUR [1] => EUR  )[qty] => 6[item_id] => 3444[item_price] => 567 )[email2@test.com] => Array ([paypal_address] => email2@test.com[order_id] => 121[item_name] => Array  ( [0] => Product2  )[item_type] => Array  ( [0] => product  )[currency] => Array  ( [0] => EUR  )[qty] => 18[item_id] => 1233[item_price] => 120 ))
```

**Note:** Make changes in code according to your requirement

Answer (score 0):

```
    $details =Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( [order_id] => 121 [item_id] => 4344 [item_name] => Product [item_price] => 123 [item_type] => product [paypal_address] => email@test.com [qty] => 4 [currency] => EUR ) 
        [1] => Array ( [order_id] => 121 [item_id] => 3444 [item_name] => Product1 [item_price] => 444 [item_type] => product [paypal_address] => email@test.com [qty] => 2 [currency] => EUR ) 
        [2] => Array ( [order_id] => 121 [item_id] => 1233 [item_name] => Product2 [item_price] => 120 [item_type] => product [paypal_address] => email2@test.com [qty] => 18 [currency] => EUR ) 
    )
    $sorted = array();
    foreach ($details as $key => $value) {
      $add = $value['paypal_address'];
      foreach ($details as $index => $detail) {
        if ($add == $detail['paypal_address']) {
          foreach ($detail as $cat => $val) {
            if (!in_array($val, $sorted[$key][$cat])) {
              $sorted[$key][$cat][] = $val;
            }
          }
          unset($details[$index]);
        }
      }
    }
// Output array
print_r($sorted);
```